# Is it possible to move or position a maximized window?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop

**Background**

I'm using an old legacy application that takes over the whole screen space. It does not show any window title bar. When running this application through remote desktop the windows title bar is there and the window is in maximized mode. The problem is that the lower part of the legacy application's window is outside of the screen because of the windows title bar.

I'm running remote desktop in full screen mode.

**Question**

Is it possible to move or position a maximized window outside of the screen? Are there any tools that can do this?

I know it seems odd to move a maximized window but if I could just offset the top position of the maximized window I would be able to see the whole legacy application when using remote desktop.

Comment: You say 'The problem is that the lower part of the window is outside of the screen because of the windows title bar.' Is this the remote desktop title bar? If so does running RDP fullscreen help - (Ctrl-Alt-Break will usually switch between full-screen and window.)

Comment: I'm running remote desktop in fullscreen so RDP is not the problem, at least not visually. I've updated the question, thanks for making the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the issue, but [WinSuperMaximize](http://code.google.com/p/winsupermaximize/) is a utility that can hide the title bar which gives you a little bit extra space.

Free and works on XP, but it did not work for me on Windows 7.

Comment: WinSuperMaximize does the exact thing I was looking for but unfortunately the nasty piece of legacy application i'm working with actually fights back. When the title bar is gone the legacy application throws up a horizontal and a vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 3):

NirCmd seems to be the right tool for the task: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

More specifically the subcommands:

```
nircmd win -style ...
```

to force or remove the titlebar or

```
nircmd win center ...
nircmd win setsize ...
```

to position the window.

As an example:
I found this useful for games, which i don't want to run in real fullscreen mode but in maximized borderless window mode, where

```
nircmd win -style stitle "Wing" 0x00C00000
```

to switch to the correct mode and

```
nircmd win setsize stitle "Wing" 0 0 1600 1200
```

to position the drawing area of the window which title starts with "Wing" to fill the specified rectangle.

As a simple command line utility this can be easily set up into a batch file with the problematic program itself to correct its display automatically each launch

Answer (score 0):

Does Alt + Space bring up the window menu and allow you (with the cursor and enter keys) to shift it across/up as required?